# SharePoint reporting services integration

Tags: 2013, permissions, reporting-services, sql, login

I am using the **SharePoint report services integration**.
I deployed a report to a document library, but when I try to view the report (form SP), I receive this error:

> login failed for user 'nt authority anonymous logon' sharepoint

If I open the report (with the same user) from the report builder client, it is working fine.
What is it wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the Credentials of the Report Data Source please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198312.aspx for details on this. We use a single database user account (the 'ReportUser') and stored credentials. This has been inherited from our stand alone configuration and works fine in SharePoint. Report Builder is running fine because it's using your windows credentials. There are a few configuration issues so read the Microsoft page carefully. Particularly if your report server is on a different computer to your SharePoint server.